# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Creating default object from empty value (View: D:\

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, backend

I am Newbie. I'm trying to return a view when i go to (for instance with selected id) /home/1 but i get this following error:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Creating default object from empty value (View: D:\Michael..\resources\views\home.blade.php)

this is my route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/home/{team_id}', 'HomeController@materialID');
```

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Team;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $code = \App\Team::where('team_name',"Coding")->get();
        $design = \App\Team::where('team_name',"Design")->get();
        $qa = \App\Team::where('team_name',"Quality Assurance")->get();
        $ana = \App\Team::where('team_name',"Analytics")->get();
        return view('home',compact('code','design','qa','ana'));
    }

    public function materialID($team_id)
    {
        $material = Team::find($team_id);
        return view('material', compact('material')); 
    }
}
```

This is how i call it in my blade

```
<a href="{{ url('home',$material->team_id = '1')}}">
     <h3>{{$code[0]->team_name}}</h3>
     <p style="padding-right: 35px">{{$code[0]->team_description}}</p>
</a>
```

i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
<a href="{{ url('home','1')}}">
     <h3>{{$code[0]->team_name}}</h3>
     <p style="padding-right: 35px">{{$code[0]->team_description}}</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. it very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Pass the team id as a param to the url:

```
<a href="{{ url('home',['team_id'=>$material->team_id])}}">
</a>
```